# Learn about occurred events from other class

Tags: c++, qt, events, qwidget, qevent

I have two classes:

```
typedef std::shared_ptr<AdaptedWidget> window_ptr;

class WindowManager
{
public:
...
private:
    std::stack<window_ptr> m_windowsStack;
}
```

and

```
class AdaptedWidget: public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    AdaptedWidget(AdaptedWidget *parent = 0);
    bool event(QEvent *event);
};

bool AdaptedWidget::event(QEvent *event)
{
    if (event->type() == QEvent::NonClientAreaMouseButtonPress ||
        event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonPress)
    {
        qDebug() << "mainwindwo press";
    }
    return QWidget::event(event);
}
```

I need to get information about events that happen in `AdaptedWidget` objects from my `WindowManager` object, How can I do that?

Comment: one can listen to events(subscribe) or another can tell events occurred(publish).

Comment: @hg_git please give me some example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Event filters](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/eventsandfilters.html#event-filters) are the Qt way to accomplish your task.

Make your `WindowManager` class a subclass of `QObject` and provide an implementation for its [`eventFilter()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#eventFilter) method.

After that, every time you create an `AdaptedWidget` use [`installEventFilter()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#installEventFilter) to install your `WindowManager` instance as an event filter on it.

```
class WindowManager : public QObject
{
public:
...
bool eventFilter(QObject* obj, QEvent* ev);

private:
    std::stack<window_ptr> m_windowsStack;
}
```

and

```
bool WindowManager::eventFilter(QObject* obj, QEvent* ev){
    AdaptedWidget* widget= qobject_cast<AdaptedWidget*>(obj);
    if(ev->type == /*type of event you are interested in*/){
        //you can compare widget against the stack of widgets you have

        //if you want to stop widget from receiving the event you can return true
    }
    return false;
}
```

and when creating each `AdaptedWidget` instance, install the `WindowManager` as an event filter:

```
AdaptedWidget* widget= new AdaptedWidget;
widget->installEventFilter(/*your WindowManager instance*/);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `AdaptedWidget` class should have a signal that indicates a mouse press, e.g.

```
class AdaptedWidget : ... {
  Q_OBJECT
  ...
public:
  Q_SIGNAL void mousePress(const QPoint &);
};

bool AdaptedWidget::event(QEvent *event)
{
    if (event->type() == QEvent::NonClientAreaMouseButtonPress ||
        event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonPress)
    {
        auto ev = static_cast<QMouseEvent*>(event);
        emit mousePress(ev->pos());
        qDebug() << "mainwindow press";
    }
    return QWidget::event(event);
}
```

Another approach is to use event filters, but that unnecessarily tightly couples the two classes.